# How to schedule a series of stored procedures to run sequentially?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, execution, sequential

I am new to coding in SQl and new to Oracle SQL developer as well.
I managed to re-build an old MS Access database in Oracle . I have stored they queries in procedures but now I need to run the procedures in a specific order, a bit like you would do in a MS Access Macro.
The goal is to be able to create a daily routine that should be launched by the scheduler.
is there a way to accomplish this?

ie "macro full run"

1. run procedure a and when it is finished
2. run procedure b and when it is finished
3. run procedure c and so on....

thank you in advance
Valentina

Comment: you can use dbms_scheduler.  read up on that.

Comment: ... specifically, [job chains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/scheduling-jobs-with-oracle-scheduler.html#GUID-BF3AB6EB-BC19-4303-9E02-6466804BA119) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MACRO_FULL_RUN AS
BEGIN
  PROCEDURE_A;
  PROCEDURE_B;
  PROCEDURE_C;
  ... and so on
END;
```

And then put it in the scheduler:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.Create_job (
      job_name          => 'MY_JOB_THAT_RUNS_DAILY',
      repeat_interval   => 'FREQ=DAILY',
      job_type          => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
      job_action        => 'MACRO_FULL_RUN',
      enabled           => TRUE
   );
END;
```

Comment: oh! now I feel a little silly! thank you so much!